# Simple named anchor doesn't work in FF but it does in IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer, firefox

I have `a href` link:

```
/agenda/#Testevent
```

Which in IE it goes to the corresponding `<h4>` element but in Firefox it doesn't work.

I have used this named anchor:

```
<h4 name="#Testevent" id="#Testevent">
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can either do this:

```
<h4><a name="Testevent">Title</a></h4>
```

Or else you can also do this:

```
<h4 id="Testevent">Title</h4>
```

"Destination anchors in HTML documents may be specified either by the A element (naming it with the name attribute), or by any other element (naming with the id attribute)."

Source: [w3.org: Links in HTML documents](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#h-12.1.1)

Answer (score 7):

Drop the '#'

name="Testevent"

Comment: Actually, it is the `id` attribute that needs to drop the `#`.

Comment: If you want to link to an anchor with the name #foo you have to use page.html#%23foo, which is nasty and doesn't make sense. The name is the name. The # is just a character in URIs that indicates a fragment id will follow.

Comment: @remi: Maybe you didn't notice, but the OP is using an `<h4>` tag not an `<a>`.

Comment: @Daniel : I'm sorry ! 
@alex : You can't do an anchor with a hn tag, you have to use an anchor tag : <a>, even if it works under some browser, please respect standard.

Comment: @remi: Actually the HTML 4.01 standard (http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#h-12.1.1) does allow you to use any element as an anchor, but it has to be identified with the `id` attribute instead of with the `name`. Therefore the OP can use `<h4 id="Testevent"></h4>`. I tested this with the latest versions of Firefox, Chrome and IE, and it works fine.